# Solution to add zero in output URL

Tags: javascript

I need a script for adding zeros after URL like shown below.. **The zeros should keep on adding for the next one** :)

```
https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl=0
https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl=00
https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl=000
https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl=0000
```

I did try this but no use.

```
function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}
var rString = randomString(32, '0');
```

Comment: Why not just get the URL, then append 0's to it?

Answer (score 0):

If your get 32 zeros, add curly braces (`{}`) to your `for` loop.

```
function randomString(length, chars) {
   var result = '';
   for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) 
   {
        result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
        return result;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That function looks like it's generating a random string, not adding 0's on the end of a URL (*hint*, you need to start with the URL instead of an empty string). But to do so is quite easy. Just get the URL with `document.URL`, then add 0's to it.

```
var length = 10;                                 // (example) For 10 zeros
var result = document.URL;                       // You need to get the URL
for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += "0";  // Then add zeros
```

Answer (score 0):

The way this is written it will only return the first result OR the last result in @Mai example. Also rString and result is a string which can only hold one value so no matter what it will only return one of them. You can try an array instead. You can see it running here http://jsfiddle.net/p4arbzcu/

> ```
> function randomString(length, chars) { // not sure why this function is called randomString...
>     var result = []; // holds url endings 
>     var urlEnd = ""; // holds current url
>     for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) {
>         urlEnd += chars;
>         result[result.length] = urlEnd; // adds current url to url endings
>     }
>     return result; }
>
> var rString = randomString(4, '0'); 
> window.alert(rString); // displays allert with url endings array
> ```